# As an application what are differences between sqlplus.exe and sqlplusw.exe?

Tags: oracle-10g, sqlplus

Currently i am using Oracle 10g and i can use both sqlplus and sqlplusw. But is there any difference in using them. And, is any of the is deprecated in newer versions?

Answer (score 2):

sqlplusw was a GUI version of the command line tool sqlplus, with its own Edit menu etc.

sqlplusw was removed in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Is there any core difference between them, like in functionality?

Comment: No idea. I do remember preferring the generic sqlplus version because it worked better. Googling, I see that sqlplusw didn't properly support commands such as `host`.